# Duplicate nested class produced by xjc

Tags: xml, jaxb, xjc

I have XML like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Records xmlns="...">
        <Some>
            ...
            <Records>
                <Record>
                </Record>
            </Records>
        </Some>
    </Records>
```

I generate XDS and after that generate classes:

```
xjc some.xsd
```

So, i have following structure:

[image: duplicate]

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Why is it a problem?  Yes, it's a bit ugly but the nested class doesn't clash with the outermost one as you can refer to it with its qualified name `Records.Some.Records`.

Comment: Because i get error: "duplicate classes", and if i want auto unmarshaling - i need valid classes, without any manual modification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an external binding file to rename the class generated from a complex type.  Below is an example where the class corresponding to the complex type `itemType` would be generated as `Item`.

```
<jxb:bindings 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    version="2.1">

    <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="your-schema.xsd">
            <jxb:bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='itemType']">
                <jxb:class name="Item"/>
            </jxb:bindings>
    </jxb:bindings>

</jxb:bindings>
```

You specify the binding file in the XJC call using the `-b` flag

```
xjc -b binding.xml your-schema.xsd
```